# How to add an overview polyline to my angular google maps

Tags: angular, google-maps, polyline, angular-google-maps

I am working with Angular Google Maps and specifically the Directions API and so I am able to see an overview polyline using the DirectionsService, but I don't understand how to implement that overview polyline in my agm window

I tried to use legs initially however that did not work as it just gave me functions which would have been overly complicated.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what you're trying to do? Are you using [this library](https://angular-maps.com/)? Are you trying to use `<agm-polyline>`? What code have you tried and what specifically do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Angular Google Maps (aka angular-maps.com -> agm/core) and tried to use the DirectionRenderer and DirectionService but it never worked for me. However I found a [solution online](https://www.leonelngande.com/directive-to-render-google-maps-direction-route-in-angular/) where you can create a Directive and a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agm-direction) that helped you do the same thing.